# Custom Grid for One Vendor

Tags: collection, reports, collection-filtering, order-grid

I'm still working my way around Magento so I apologize ahead of time for my lack of knowledge.  I have a custom report with the collection coming from the a model.  I need my report to show only one vendor that I specify.  I have an attribute, `manufacturer_label`, coming from the model into a column in the grid.  That is the vendor name.  I just need the grid to show orders from only one vendor that I specify.  Is this something I can do in the `_prepareCollection()` function?

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    // Get the data collection from the model
    $this->getCollection()->initReport('vendorreport/vendorreport');

    return $this;
}
```

Inside `_prepareColumns()` I'm adding the Vendor column like this in case it helps:

```
    $this->addColumn('manufacturer_label', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('vendorreport')->__('Vendor'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'sortable' => true,
        'index' => 'manufacturer_label'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter by manufacturer use:

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldtoFilter('manufacturer_label', $value);
```